# Rust target-cpu=native gets slower SIMD execution

Tags: rust, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm making a simple test of the Rust wrappers for x86 intrinsics: the approximation of PI by the Leibniz series:

```
#[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]
use std::arch::x86_64::*;

fn main() {
    let mut n: u64 = 0;
    let pi4 = std::f64::consts::PI / 4.0;
    unsafe {
        let mut dens = _mm256_set_pd(1.0f64, -3.0f64, 5.0f64, -7.0f64);
        let adder = _mm256_set_pd(8.0f64, -8.0f64, 8.0f64, -8.0f64);
        let ones = _mm256_set1_pd(1.0f64);
        let mut rsum = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0f64);
        let mut quotients: __m256d;
        loop {
            quotients = _mm256_div_pd(ones, dens);
            rsum = _mm256_add_pd(rsum, quotients);
            dens = _mm256_add_pd(dens, adder);
            n = n + 1;
            let vlow = _mm256_extractf128_pd(rsum, 0);
            let vhigh = _mm256_extractf128_pd(rsum, 1);
            let add_partial = _mm_add_pd(vlow, vhigh);
            let sum = _mm_cvtsd_f64(add_partial)
                + _mm_cvtsd_f64(_mm_unpackhi_pd(add_partial, add_partial));
            if f64::abs(pi4 - sum) < 1.0e-9 {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    println!("Steps: {}", 4 * n);
}
```

Functionally, the program works as expected. My CPU model is "AMD A8-9600 RADEON R7", and:

```
$ rustc --target=x86_64-linux-kernel --print target-cpus
Available CPUs for this target:
    native         - Select the CPU of the current host (currently bdver4).
```

When compiling with:

```
$ cargo build --release
```

The time is:

```
$ time target/release/sotest 
real    0m1.668s
user    0m1.667s
sys 0m0.001s
```

But with the "native" target it runs slower:

```
$ RUSTFLAGS="-C target-cpu=native" cargo build --release
...
$ time target/release/sotest
real    0m2.783s
user    0m2.778s
sys 0m0.004s
```

The question is what's wrong with the "native" target-cpu? At first sight of the [documentation](https://rust-lang.github.io/packed_simd/perf-guide/target-feature/rustflags.html), I expected a binary leveraging all my CPU's provided extensions:

> The compiler will translate this into a list of target features.

Even if it does not consider the extensions, why did get slower?

BTW, compiling selecting the avx extension generates a big boost:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-C target-feature=+avx" cargo build --release
...
real    0m0.358s
user    0m0.354s
sys 0m0.004s
```

EDIT: Using Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.0-72-generic.
rustc 1.51.0

Comment: Separate from the slowdown, you'd normally want to do multiple iterations before the horizontal-sum work.  Also, Bulldozer-family only has 128-bit wide SIMD execution units, so 256-bit vector instructions decode to 2 uops.  Using two separate 128-bit vectors would avoid the `_mm256_extractf128_pd(vec, 1)` at basically no extra cost.  It's cheap (single uop for any port or BD, and Zen1), but free is even better.  The `_mm_unpackhi_pd` is also not free, but using SIMD for division is probably worth it.  (In fact you probably bottleneck on division latency, and that can hide the hsum work.)

Comment: "In fact you probably bottleneck on division latency, and that can hide the hsum work"... Indeed that is what is happening. When testing, I've tried to do the additions only once per every 16 loops, with no noticeable time variation: division rules total time. Sad to know about the Bulldozer "limitation".

Comment: Yeah, given the latency bottleneck, there's probably nothing to gain unless you can usefully unroll with another vector of 4 elements to be running two dep chains in parallel.  The 2x `vaddpd` are separate, the longest *loop-carried* dep being only through `vdivpd`.  But even on Excavator (bdver4), the FP divider is partially pipelined.  8-22 cycle latency, but 8-16 cycle throughput.  (https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).  So there's maybe a little bit of room to unroll with another 128-bit or 256-bit vector of denominators to max out FP division throughput.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you're hitting this bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/83027, which was resolved on March 17, 2021 by https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/83084.

The bug is that when `native` is used, `target_feature` isn't applied correctly, which is what all of the intrinsics use. As a result, your calls to the intrinsic functions probably aren't being inlined. You should look at a profile to confirm that.

More generally, I would recommend using runtime CPU feature detection and correct use of `#[target_feature]`. You should only be calling functions that operate on 32-byte vectors from functions that have at least the `avx` feature enabled.

Comment: Yes, thank you. As suggested in the bug discussion, being explicit: target-cpu=bdver4 fixed my problem with 1.51 stable. Also, "native" target woks as expected in nightly 1.51.